# How to get User info using JS SDK after they login with Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I have this in my header:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Then I have the FB login button code like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myAppId&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="user_hometown,user_about_me,email,user_address"
autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1">
</fb:login-button>
```

Then after the user logs in with the FB button, how do I make a JS call to get their name, email, photo, etc?

I also found some code like this, but not sure where this is used:

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'myAppId',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelURL : 'http://www.comehike.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
</script>
```

Do I need the code right above?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need `FB.init` code to initialise the Facebook JavaScript SDK and parse the XFBML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="user_hometown,user_about_me,email,user_address" autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>


    <!-- put this before the end body tag -->
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : 'myAppId',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
        channelURL : 'http://www.comehike.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
        oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To get logged users data:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

If all went well `response` should be a JSON object containing the user data you have permission to view.

The users image can be gotten from:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture
```

You can specify the size you want with the type argument

- square - 50x50
- small - 50 pixels wide, variable height
- normal - 100 pixels wide, variable height
- large - about 200 pixels wide, variable height

For example:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID/picture?type=large
```

Comment: @jBut Hmmm, I have this stuff here: http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php and I can't get the FB button to render.  Are you able to view source on it and see the fb code by any chance?

Comment: By the way, what is supposed to be in channel.html file? I don't have that file :)

Comment: Your xfbml is commmented out.

Comment: Hmmm, the xfbml isn't commented out.  I uncommented it and it still doesn't render the login button...any idea what can be wrong with it?

Comment: @Genadinik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2073/discussion-between-jbit-and-genadinik)