# Retrieve data from facebook api for a user

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey so I am having a hard time understanding how to retrieve data from a user who logs in to my site, I am currently using the javascript sdk but I am trying to figure out how to request the user's data correctly and then how to send it to my server side... I thought it might be something like

```
req.body.id
```

for the facebook user id, but I do not think that is it...

Here is the javascript code  on my login page.

```
script(src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js')
div#fb-root
    script.
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId: 'blank', // App ID from the app dashboard
                //channelUrl:'//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
                status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
                xfbml      : true,                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
                cookie: true
            });



        };



        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));


        function authUser() {
                FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'email, user_likes'});

                function checkLoginStatus(response) {
                    if(response && response.status == 'connected') {
                        alert('User is authorized');
                        document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'none';
                        console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
                        var uid = response.authoResponse.userID;
                        var accessToken = response.authoResponse.accessToken;
            testAPI();
                        getFBData ();
                    } else {
                        alert('User is not authorized');
                        document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
                    }
                }


            }


        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' + response.id);
            });
        };

        function getFBData () {
            FB.api('/me', function(data){
                alert(data.first_name + data.last_name + data.id);
            })
        };
        function fbLogout() {
            FB.logout(function (response) {
                //window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); is a redirect
                window.location.reload();
            });
        }




    div.centerContent
            form(method="POST", action="/login")
                fieldset
                    legend Login
                    input(type="email", name="email", placeholder="Email", maxlength="20", value= "")   
                    br
                    input(type="password", name="password", id="password", placeholder="Password", maxlength="20", value= "")   
                    br
                    input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="login", value="Login")
                    a(href="/")
                        button.btn(type="button") Cancel
            <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
            button#fbLogout(type="button", onclick="fbLogout()") Logout of FB
            button#fbLogin(type="button", onclick="authUser()") Login to FB
```

It is in jade but it should be readable.

Any help or direction on how to actually grab a user's info(in particular I am looking for a profile picture, access token, user id, first and last name)

Thanks.

EDIT:

I am using node.js and mongodb on the backend

Comment: I don't know from where did you get this code, but I would recommend you to follow the steps from the Developers Site - [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/).  Your answer starts with the "Add the login code" part in the link.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... it is from getting started and some of my own tweaks and code added to get the info i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with your code.
The biggest one I think is that you don't use the reponse inside the callback!
Others are just wrong spelling of variables like authResponse and authoResponse.

Try this:

```
    function authUser() {
            FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope:'email, user_likes'});

            function checkLoginStatus(response) {
                if(!response || response.status !== 'connected') {
                    alert('User is not authorized');
                    document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    alert('User is authorized');
                    document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'none';
                    console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);

                    //This has to be in your callback!
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    testAPI();
                    getFBData();
                }
            }
        }


    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' + response.id);
        });
    };

    function getFBData () {
        FB.api('/me', function(data){
            alert(data.first_name + data.last_name + data.id);
        })
    };
    function fbLogout() {
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            //window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); is a redirect
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for those finds, should I be adding a function after scope for the callback and then throw it above testAPI etc.? Also, do you know how I would call the file from the server side is it req.body.something or am I suppose to post the JSON i receive somehow?

Comment: why do you want another callback? the callback for the FB.Login is checkLoginStatus, then inside this function you can do what you want, and launch any other functions you want.

For the server side, you have to post data from the client to your server endpoint, and with express and the bodyparser middleware you will have access to req.body

Comment: Oh then I think I confused your this has to be in your callback? did you just mean as arguments? Because I need to somehow get the accessToken to make requests on the user's behalf

Comment: I wrote this because in your code it was not in your callback, but I put it in it in my code. And I left the comment to show you what I did.
With that code, you have the accesstoken and you can now send it to your server, or directly call the FB.api as you've done and then send the response data to your server

Comment: Oh ok, ya I did move it, I was just wondering how do I call the access token outside of it, because I tried data.accessToken and it gives me undefined? Also, how do I send it... to I add a $.post in the code of the function getFBData should that do it?

Comment: The $.post should be after you retrieve the data you want to send, so in the getFBData it could be nice. (By the way testAPI and getFBData are the same...). In the client side, you don't really need the access_token to be explicit: once the login is done and once your app is authorized, the FB.api will automatically add the token to your queries, so as long as you request the data after the authorization, you're good to go.

Comment: so I do not need the accessToken at all... I think I do if I want to allow a user to share something on their facebook from my site... I got the data working now and sent correctly just need to get the accessToken I think... so I can create share buttons that post on their facebook

Comment: Ok I think you were right that I do not need the token... because of the sdk thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can tell from your code is that your login function should be made asynchronous like this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   var uid = response.authoResponse.userID;
   var accessToken = response.authoResponse.accessToken;
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Also, when you mention that you would like to pass FB user info to the server side, when a user logs in on the client side, the server side information should already be accessible through the FB PHP SDK. The documentation for this can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

An example of a PHP call that would provide you with the user info on the server is:

```
$me = $Facebook->api('/me');
```

Comment: Sorry didnt clarify, but I am using Node.js on the backend, and I am calling a function up top for getFBData but I do not know how to call it and if I am grabbing it wrong...

Comment: Also, I was calling the checkLoginStatus arg so I can check if a user is already logged in or not...

Comment: Ah ok. Well for starters I would try moving your authUser() and checkLoginStatus() functions outside of the window.fbAsyncInit function to see if that fixes your login button issue. I think the window.fbAsyncInit function is only meant to include the call to init() and event listeners.

Comment: Well the point of the init is to see right off the bat if the user is logged in that is why I think it needs to stay in there... so the user does not have to call the function

Comment: According to FB's js SDK documentation located in the "Checking user status on page load" section of this link [link]http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/, in order to get the login status on page load, set _status_ to _true_ in the init function then subscribe to the auth.statusChange event like this: `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
  alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});`

Comment: And also, thanks the login button now works with that edit but ya still not able to retrieve the user's data?

Comment: To get the user's info, make a call to FB.api('/me', function(response) { ... }); after the user has logged in. A more detailed explanation of this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6915931/2704706

Comment: Great that actually helps for retrieving the photo and everything but now how do I call it from the server side is it a req.body.something or how do I call the JSON file, or do I have to POST it on my own?