# how to develop login with facebook account in asp.net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, asp.net-4.5

we are going to develop SharePoint 2013 web site in asp .net 4.5.
 In this, we are using **asp .net membership provider** to login the site. we want to integrate facebook login in addition with this site.
 user can login to this site his credential stored on our aspnetdb or ***Using  Facebook Credential*** and it will be authenticated in our site.

**in case** he login with his facebook account we should get his information and stored in our database

Please suggest me on this!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook Javascript SDK. 
The idea is simple:

- register on Facebook, if you already are not
- register as Developer
- register your APP and obtain APP specific crypto key
- use that key in order to be able to access Facebook services from JS.

Facebook in our office unfortunately blocked, so I can not provide you with a link to official documentation, you have to search it by yourself.

But here you can find a simple tutorial: [Facebook Javascript SDK Tutorial](http://hayageek.com/facebook-javascript-sdk/)

Comment: Thank You for your help,i do the first step and i obtain the key, but about the JS i was searched and i found many different solution, i will research again to obtain the official documentation.
I hop to some one guide me to the right way

Comment: @user2508328: the easiest I found is in SDK itself: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/, using FB.ui, so appears FB standard login window, or it logs if there is already security cookie available.

Comment: This is very useful, but about the second Point in my question <<"in case he login with his facebook account we should get his information and stored in our database if he is a new user >>" 
What i should to do on my Server Side Code !!! Regards

Comment: @user2508328: don't think this is actually possible. you *may* store information about a fact that given user *has* FB account, but what that account is, not very sure if you can do that.

Comment: in my case i want to register this new user on my site.
This is my idea

Comment: @user2508328: try have a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915860/how-to-get-user-info-using-js-sdk-after-they-login-with-facebook